# Get random gamma distribution in tensorflow like numpy.random.gamma

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

Hi I am new to tensorflow and I am trying to generate random gamma distribution in tensorflow just like numpy.random.gamma

My numpy code is :-

```
self._lambda = 1 * np.random.gamma(100., 1. / 100, (self.n_topic, self.n_voca))
```

where `n_topic=240` and `n_voca=198`

My tensorflow code is :-

```
 self._tf_lambda = tf.random_gamma((self.n_topic, self.n_voca),1, dtype=tf.float32, seed=0, name='_tf_lambda')
```

Is it a correct implementation? I believe I failed to understand the parameters of `tf.random_gamma` became `self._lambda <> self.tf_lambda`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting different shape parameters in your distribution, so it is expected that they differ.

One thing to watch out for is that numpy has a "scale" parameter while TF has an "inverse scale" parameter. So one has to be inverted to get the same distribution.

Jupyter notebook example with matching distributions:

```
%matplotlib inline
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = (50000,)
shape_parameter = 1.5
scale_parameter = 0.5
bins = np.linspace(-1, 5, 30)

np_res = np.random.gamma(shape=shape_parameter, scale=scale_parameter, size=size)

# Note the 1/scale_parameter here

tf_op = tf.random_gamma(shape=size, alpha=shape_parameter, beta=1/scale_parameter)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf_res = sess.run(tf_op)

plt.hist(tf_res, bins=bins, alpha=0.5);
plt.hist(np_res, bins=bins, alpha=0.5);
```

[image: Histogram plot of results]